# Code box size and font size in RPres

Tags: r, rpres

I've worked in the past a good deal with knitr and beamer for slides. One thing I'm noticing now with R Presentations that dynamic sizing of both the code box and the size of the code font seems to be missing. With knitr/beamer I could easily change font size with the size argument (e.g., size="footnote" worked for denser slides) as well as changing the code box width for my slides with options(width=...).

I'm struggling with how to do this in the current implementation of R Presentations - any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

@Florian's answer didn't work for me. I found a [solution here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/27777_55697c3a476640caa0ad2099fe914ae5.html#/9) that seems cleaner - credit to Andy Lyons for this fix.

Define a new style for smaller code at the beginning of the document, then apply it whenever you want the slide to use smaller code.

Here's an example of how to do it:

````
Presentation Title
========================================================
author: Jane Doe
transition: none

<style>
.small-code pre code {
  font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

Slide 1 - large code
========================================================
Regular slide text here

```{r}
head(cars)
```
Slide 2 - small code
========================================================
class: small-code

More regular slide text...
```{r}
head(cars)
```
````

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the font size, wrapping the chunk in

```
<font size="X"> CHUNK </font>
```

worked for me.