# Knitr ioslides: customize code chunk size

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, pandoc, ioslides

[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646333/code-chunk-font-size-in-rmarkdown-with-knitr-and-latex) and other resources, my understanding is the when setting up CSS for an Rmarkdown presentation, code.r{} should control the parameters for echoed code, while pre{} should control the size of the output. However, pre{} seems to be changing both and code.r{} is doing nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

````
---
title: "CSStest"
author: "Me"
date: "December 27, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---
<style type="text/css">

body{ /* Normal  */
   font-size: 16px;
}
code.r{ /* Code block */
  font-size: 4px;
}
pre {
  font-size: 42px
}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

---
### Slide with R Output
```{r echo = TRUE}
##here is some R code
1+3

##Why is the output the same size as the code?
```
````

[image: here is what I get:]

I am using Pandoc 2.0.5, rmarkdown_1.8.5, and knitr_1.15.1 on Windows.

Edit: This is the html for the slide I screencapped:

```
<slide class=""><hgroup><h2></h2></hgroup><article >

<h3>Slide with R Output</h3>

<pre class = 'prettyprint lang-r'>##here is some R code
1+3</pre>

<pre >## [1] 4</pre>

<pre class = 'prettyprint lang-r'>##Why is the output the same size as the code?</pre></article></slide>


  <slide class="backdrop"></slide>

</slides>
```

I also tried a slightly different approach to customize my slides on a per-slide basis, described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612385/code-box-size-and-font-size-in-rpres).

````
---
title: "CSStest"
author: "Me"
date: "December 27, 2017"
output: ioslides_presentation
---
Presentation Title
========================================================
author: Jane Doe
transition: none

<style>
.small-code pre code {
  font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

Slide 1 - large code
========================================================
Regular slide text here

```{r}
head(cars)
```
Slide 2 - small code
========================================================
class: small-code

More regular slide text...
```{r}
head(cars)
```
````

but again, no change in font size

update: I realized that there was a newer version of Knitr, but with knitr_1.17 I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: As you can see in your HTML output, the code is inside a `pre` element with classes `lang-r` and `prettyprint`. So change `code.r` to `pre.lang-r`.

Comment: Yes, that did it! If you put it as an answer, I will mark it answered.
I guess my next question to research is where code.r, pre, and pre-lang.r are connected with the html that actually gets generated. Is the issue that the package is changing rapidly, so what used to be called code.r is now called pre-lang.r?